# How to draw a collection of small bipartite graphs in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw simple graphs in latex with tikz.

My figure that I would like to produce looks like this and I would like to put it in beamer.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have some ideas about it to share or are you just stumped from the beginning?

Comment: What are bipartite graphs? I'm afraid they just look like squiggles to me, but I'm sure there's more to it than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I define some building blocks and then use `tikzcd` for typesetting the blocks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\pairsolid}{\bullet \arrow[r] \& \bullet}
\newcommand{\pairdashed}{\bullet \arrow[r,dashed] \& \bullet}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[nodes={inner sep=-1pt},arrows=-,ampersand replacement=\&]
\pairdashed \& \pairsolid  \& \pairsolid  \& \pairdashed \\
\pairsolid  \& \pairdashed \& \pairsolid  \& \pairsolid  \\
\pairdashed \& \pairdashed \& \pairdashed \& \pairdashed
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can reduce the distances:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\pairsolid}{\bullet \arrow[r] \& \bullet}
\newcommand{\pairdashed}{\bullet \arrow[r,dashed] \& \bullet}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  nodes={inner sep=-1pt},
  arrows=-,
  ampersand replacement=\&,
  row sep=1ex,
  column sep=1.2em,
]
\pairdashed \& \pairsolid  \& \pairsolid  \& \pairdashed \\
\pairsolid  \& \pairdashed \& \pairsolid  \& \pairsolid  \\
\pairdashed \& \pairdashed \& \pairdashed \& \pairdashed
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the size of the graph? Or make the length of the arrow small?

Comment: @Kira Yes, of course. Reduce `column sep` and `row sep`.